# Error when compiling simple Qwt program on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Tags: c++, osx-lion, qwt

I'm trying to get the following c++ program using Qwt v. 6.0.1 to work:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <QApplication>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QwtPlot plot(QwtText("CppQwtExample1"));
   plot.setGeometry(0,0,640,400);
   plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, 0.0, 2.0*M_PI);
   plot.setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, -1.0, 1.0);

   QwtPlotCurve sine("Sine");
   std::vector<double> xs;
   std::vector<double> ys;
   for (double x=0; x<2.0*M_PI; x+=(M_PI/10.0)) {
      xs.push_back(x);
      ys.push_back(std::sin(x));
   }
   sine.setData(&xs[0], &ys[0], xs.size());
   sine.attach(&plot);

   plot.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

and the .pro file looks like:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = CppQwtExample1
QMAKEFEATURES += /usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/features
CONFIG += qwt
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/lib/qwt.framework/Headers
LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/lib/qwt.framework/Versions/6/ \
 -lqwt
SOURCES += qwtTest.cpp
```

However, when I now try to do

qmake

make

I get the error:

ld: library not found for -lqwt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qwtTest.app/Contents/MacOS/qwtTest] Error 1

I surely miss something here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/lib/qwt.framework/Versions/6/ -lqwt
```

This is wrong. Due to the naming conventions of Mac OS X frameworks, the dynamic library inside qwt.framework isn't named "libqwt.dylib" (which the linker requires), but simply "qwt".
Use

```
LIBS += -F/usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/lib -framework qwt
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick. I can compile the program now without any errors. However, now when I try to open the resulting application I get an Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded: qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwtReferenced from: /Users/USER/*/qwtTest.app/Contents/MacOS/qwtTest
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Ok, by following the discussion on http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-37278.html I have managed to get rid of the error by making use of a softlink: sudo ln -s /usr/local/qwt-6.0.1/lib/qwt.framework/qwt /usr/lib/qwt. The program still crashes for some reason, but at least I do not get any errors regarding libraries which cannot be found or loaded.