# Qwt framework not found

Tags: qt, osx-mavericks, qwt

Good Morning,

I am currently trying to build a project in QT that uses the Qwt library. However, when I try to build the project I get

```
warning: directory not found for option '-F/usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib'
error:framework not found qwt
error:linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I have followed the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588418/install-and-use-qwt-under-mac-os-x%20this) post as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540666/error-when-compiling-simple-qwt-program-on-mac-osx-10-7-4) post but it still cannot find the framework

I am using Xcode 6, Qwt 6, QT 5.3, and Mac OSX 10.9.

My .pro file's relevant code is as follows:

```
#mac: QMAKE_MAC_SDK.macosx.path = Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Patforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
#mac: QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.9 #Added to help build QWT 
#INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/qwt.prf 
include (/usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/qwt.prf )           
#CONFIG += qwt

#macx:QMAKE_MAC_SDK += macosx10.9
QMAKEFEATURES += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/features 
CONFIG += qwt 
#mac:INCLUDEPATH += /Library/Frameworks/qwt.framework/Headers
#mac: INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/src
mac: INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local.qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.framework/Headers
linux-g++:INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/include
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qwt-5.2.1/include 
FORMS += ui/ 
    UI_HEADERS_DIR = inc_ui 
    OBJECTS_DIR = obj 
    MOC_DIR = moc 
#mac:LIBS += /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib -framework qwt 
#mac:LIBS += -l /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.framework
mac:LIBS += -F /usr/local/qwt-6.1.0/lib -framework qwt
linux-g++:LIBS += /usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib/libqwt.so
win32:LIBS += C:/Qwt-5.2.1/lib/qwt5.dll
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: you compiled the "qwt" or just extracted the compact version?

Comment: I downloaded from [Sourceforge](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/), and followed their install steps of qmake, make, and sudo make install (aside from the steps in the above posts)